# Python : When is a variable passed by reference and when by value?

Tags: python, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

My code :

```
locs = [ [1], [2] ]
for loc in locs:
    loc = []

print locs
# prints => [ [1], [2] ]
```

Why is `loc` not reference of elements of `locs` ?

Python : Everything is passed as reference unless explicitly copied [ Is this not True ? ]

Please explain.. how does python decides **referencing and copying** ?

**Update :**

How to do ?

```
def compute(ob):
   if isinstance(ob,list): return process_list(ob)
   if isinstance(ob,dict): return process_dict(ob)

for loc in locs:
   loc = compute(loc)  # What to change here to make loc a reference of actual locs iteration ?
```

- locs must contain the final processed response !
- I don't want to use `enumerate`, is it possible without it ?

Comment: Everything is passed by value, but every value is just a reference  ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Everything in Python is passed and assigned by value, in the same way that everything is passed and assigned by value in Java. Every value in Python is a reference (pointer) to an object. Objects cannot be values. Assignment always copies the value (which is a pointer); two such pointers can thus point to the same object. Objects are never copied unless you're doing something explicit to copy them.

For your case, every iteration of the loop assigns an element of the list into the variable `loc`. You then assign something else to the variable `loc`. All these values are pointers; you're assigning pointers; but you do not affect any objects in any way.

Comment: In my point of view - You described it the best.
Just tell me the answer of the Update to the question - that part you missed.

Comment: So what happens with integer and float numbers then? Are they just considered immutable objects? How does python manage that as I'm sure it cannot hold all conceivable numbers in memory ready to be referenced.

Comment: @AndrewS: Integers and floats are indeed immutable (it should be apparent that they do not have methods that mutate themselves). I am not sure what the second part of your comment means.

Comment: What I'm saying by that second point is lets sat that I have two lines X = 150 and y = 150 on another. Will there be two separate copies of 150 in memory or one immutable object pooled in the same way Java Pools it's immutable Strings.

Comment: @AndrewS: Maybe they are the same and maybe they aren't. Why does it matter? This has nothing to do with mutability or semantics of assignment.

Comment: It matters when you want to understand the implementation techniques in use.

Comment: @AndrewS yes, `float` and `int` objects are... objects. And they are immutable. *Everything* in Python is an object. The behavior of the example you gave is implementation dependant, and could change given any python version, even in minor-version updates. But basically, the CPython compiler will often optimize immutable constant expressions to the same object. How and when it happens depends on a lot of things, and again, is an implementation detail

Answer (score 73):

Effbot (aka Fredrik Lundh) has described Python's variable passing style as call-by-object:  http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm

Objects are allocated on the heap and pointers to them can be passed around anywhere.

- When you make an assignment such as `x = 1000`, a dictionary entry is created that maps the string "x" in the current namespace to a pointer to the integer object containing one thousand.
- When you update "x" with `x = 2000`, a new integer object is created and the dictionary is updated to point at the new object.  The old one thousand object is unchanged (and may or may not be alive depending on whether anything else refers to the object).
- When you do a new assignment such as `y = x`, a new dictionary entry "y" is created that points to the same object as the entry for "x".
- Objects like strings and integers are *immutable*.  This simply means that there are no methods that can change the object after it has been created.  For example, once the integer object one-thousand is created, it will never change.  Math is done by creating new integer objects.
- Objects like lists are *mutable*.  This means that the contents of the object can be changed by anything pointing to the object.  For example, `x = []; y = x; x.append(10); print y` will print `[10]`.  The empty list was created.  Both "x" and "y" point to the same list.  The *append* method mutates (updates) the list object (like adding a record to a database) and the result is visible to both "x" and "y" (just as a database update would be visible to every connection to that database).

Hope that clarifies the issue for you.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't help in Python to think in terms of references or values. Neither is correct.

In Python, variables are just names. In your for loop, `loc` is just a name that points to the current element in the list. Doing `loc = []` simply *rebinds* the name `loc` to a different list, leaving the original version alone.

But since in your example, each element is a list, you could actually *mutate* that element, and that would be reflected in the original list:

```
for loc in locs:
    loc[0] = loc[0] * 2
```

Comment: It might be helpful to read *Idiomatic Python* - ["other languages have variables, Python has labels."](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) The rest of it is good reading too. ;)

Comment: How to modify each element of the container ? \

Comment: @Yugal which part of what I've written above was not clear?

Comment: Generally, I just want to process each element of my container. So, how can that be acheived ? If everything is a label that seems to be a disadvantage when actaully want to edit the element.

Comment: @YugalJindle : To modify elements in a _list_, use the square brackets to reference items in that list.

Comment: That is a specific solution for list, the loop may not always be aware of the object type. A method may be processing the loc which does different stuff for dict and list.

Answer (score 8):

When you say

```
loc = []
```

you are rebinding the `loc` variable to a newly created empty list

Perhaps you want

```
loc[:] = []
```

Which assigns a slice (which happens to be the whole list) of loc to the empty list

Comment: I believe this last example is what OP was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

Everything is passed by object. Rebinding and mutating are different operations.

```
locs = [ [1], [2] ]
for loc in locs:
    del loc[:]

print locs
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why is loc not reference of elements of locs ?

**It is**. Or at least, it is in the same sense that every other variable in Python is. Python variables are **names, not storage**. `loc` is a name that is used to refer to elements of `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, while `locs` is a name that refers to the entire structure.

```
loc = []
```

This **does not mean** "look at the thing that `loc` names, and cause it to turn into `[]`". It **cannot** mean that, because Python objects are **not capable** of such a thing.

Instead, it means "cause `loc` to stop being a name for the thing that it's currently a name for, and start instead being a name for `[]`". (Of course, it means the specific `[]` that's provided there, since in general there may be several objects in memory that are the same.)

Naturally, the contents of `locs` are unchanged as a result.