# Function in Python Setting Global Variables (without intent)

Tags: function, python-3.x, variables

I don't know if this is a problem that others get, but I have code in python that goes like this:

```
def makemove(board,move,val):
    new=board
    new[move[0]][move[1]]=val
    return new
```

My problem is that if I use this function by simply doing makemove(game,[0,1],-1) where game equals [[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]] the variable game becomes [[0, -1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]].

I have tried to look into functions setting global variables, but I have thus for not found a way to prevent makemove() from setting the variables that you put into it. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically because assignment in Python doesn't mean what you think it does, and lists are *mutable sequences*.

Lists are Python objects. The *name* `board` is merely a *label* for or *reference* to that object.
So when you say `new=board` this means "let the name `new` reference the same object as the name `board`".

In Python every object has a unique identifier that you can retrieve using `id()`. Let's create a board, do the assignment and see what happens:

```
In [1]: board = [[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]

In [2]: new = board

In [3]: id(new), id(board)
Out[3]: (34495504136, 34495504136)
```

`new` and `board` are referencing the same object.

Since a list is a mutable sequence you can change it without getting an error.

So if you want to play with any mutable sequence inside a function without modifying the original, you should use `copy.deepcopy` first to make a copy and modify that.

Comment: So in my code would board also be referencing (or have the same id) as the variable I plug in?

Comment: @NathanEaves Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone `board`.

```
import
new = copy.deepcopy(board)
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/93910 for other ways of doing this.

Your code sets elements of a variable which is a "reference". 
In other words, your variable `new` is really an array reference to `board`, i.e. it points to the same memory location. So when you change `new`, the original variable `board` gets changed.

Here's another answer on how to think about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697367/93910

Comment: I tried that out, and it works, but why is it bad to have it without the "new" variable?