# Rotation of the numbers-python

Tags: python

To find the rotations of a number I wrote a code like

```
def rotation(N):
    A=[]
    for i in range(len(N)):
        y=N.pop(0)
        N.append(y)
        A.append(N)
    return A
K=[1,9,7]
r=rotation(K)
print(r)
```

but it gives me an output like:

```
A=[[1, 9, 7], [1, 9, 7], [1, 9, 7]]
```

but it should be

```
A=[[1,9,7],[9,7,1],[7,1,9]]
```

and I didnt understand why this happens
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use collections.deque**

You should use `collections.deque` for this task and use the in-place method `deque.rotate` designed specifically for this purpose.

Using a `list` for this task would require expensive copying operations, while `deque` is optimised for fast addition and removal of elements from the beginning and end of a queue. See [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity?) for more details.

```
from collections import deque

A = deque([1, 9, 7])

for i in range(len(A)):
    print(A)
    A.rotate()

deque([1, 9, 7])
deque([7, 1, 9])
deque([9, 7, 1])
```

**Why your code does not work**

The reason your code does not work is because you are modifying the same object rather than a copy. The following will work:

```
def rotation(N):
    A = []
    for i in range(len(N)):
        N = N[:]
        N.append(N.pop(0))
        A.append(N)
    return A

K = [1,9,7]
r = rotation(K)

print(r)

[[9, 7, 1], [7, 1, 9], [1, 9, 7]]
```

**Further explanation**

If you modify the same object, `A` will consist of 3 lists with each list pointing to the same object and will therefore be *guaranteed* to be identical. Remember each list is just a bunch of pointers. If each pointer points to one object, changing it 3 times means the final assignment will be used *for all* the sublists.

Comment: Care to explain why?

Comment: @Sid, Sure, I've added more details.

Comment: Why is modifying the same object not working though?  It's an append operation, so should be fine, isn't it?

Comment: If you modify the same object, `A` will consist of 3 lists with each list pointing to the same object and will therefore be *guaranteed* to be identical. Remember each list is just a bunch of pointers. If each pointer points to one object, changing it 3 times means the final assignment will be used *for all* the sublists.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  I completely missed the object-reference relationship.  Thanks!

Comment: I didnt understandd the usage of N=N[:] what s the purpose of it ? Other then that its great to use it. I tried deque but it writes as deque in front of the each list and its not useful for me for further operations.

Comment: @user37487, `N[:]` is a **copy** of `N`. It's a *different* object, even if its contents are the same initially. You should read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696495/python-when-is-a-variable-passed-by-reference-and-when-by-value) | [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 5):

Use a simple list *slicing*:

```
def rotation(N):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(N)):
        output.append(N[i:] + N[:i])
    return output

K=[1,9,7]
r=rotation(K)
print(r)
# [[1, 9, 7], [9, 7, 1], [7, 1, 9]]
```

Comment: Why is this behavior in the first place?

Comment: As in why did the original code posted by OP does not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570334/rotation-of-the-numbers-python/50570473?noredirect=1#comment88150807_50570473

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotation(N):
    return [N[i:] + N[:i] for i in range(len(N))]
K = [1, 9, 7]
print(rotation(K))
```

Comment: This is basically the [answer of @Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50570547/8881141). You should add a different approach, not repeat, what has been already posted. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I understand. It is my fault. Didn't see his answer.

Comment: No problem. [There are so many questions unanswered...](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)

Answer (score -1):

I see what you want to do. First of all, here is an improvement:
You can spare this variable "y", so like this:

```
N.append(N.pop(0))
```

And then, you must copy the list:

```
A.append(N[:])
```

so the entire code looks like:

```
def rotation(N):
A=[]
for i in range(len(N)):
    N.append(N.pop(0))
    A.append(N[:])
return A
```

K=[1,9,7]
r=rotation(K)
print(r)

That does work. This is because of how Python manages lists. Hope this helped.