# Why does assignment of pd.DataFrame.sort_values() not work inside loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        value=np.random.rand(9) - 0.5,
        group=np.repeat(np.arange(3), 3),
        time_idx=np.tile(np.arange(3), 3),
    )
)
test_data
```

```
train_data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        value=np.random.rand(9) - 0.5,
        group=np.repeat(np.arange(3), 3),
        time_idx=np.tile(np.arange(3), 3),
    )
)
train_data
```

Why does this assignment:

```
for data in [train_data, test_data]:
    data = data.sort_values('value')
```

not leave either of train_data or test_data sorted?

Doing the assignment outside the loop works just fine. Like so:

```
train_data = train_data.sort_values('value')
```

Doing an inplace operation inside the for loop works as well:

```
for data in [train_data, test_data]:
    data.sort_values('value', inplace=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708861 This answer to a similar question clicked with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
for data in [train_data, test_data]:
    data = data.sort_values('value')
```

You take first `train_data`, sort it and assignt it as a copy to `data`. Later the same with `test_data`. Then, neither `train_data` or `test_data` are edited and the final `data` is the sorted version of `test_data` because the for-loop reassign the object.

Like if you do:

```
data = train_data 
data.sort_values('value',inplace=True)
data = test_data
data.sort_values('value',inplace=True)
```

When you do:

```
for data in [train_data, test_data]:
    data.sort_values('value', inplace=True)
```

The `inplace=True` is editing the object `data` which is also a reference to `train_data` first and `test_data` second. So they are edited too. And data is also `test_data`.

It is like you do:

```
train_data.sort_values('value',inplace=True)
data = train_data 
test_data.sort_values('value',inplace=True)
data = test_data
```

The assignment `data =`  in the for-loop works perfectly. If you actually want to sort `train_data` and `test_data` the inplace option is the one you are looking for.